# used hours to all hours used or not

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I have a column which shows the hours at which we used our tap water. so the values will be like

```
Date    Hour ending   Amount(ltrs)
1/2/14 | 5         | 0.5
1/2/14 | 10        | 16
1/2/14 | 11        | 10.5
1/2/14 | 17        | 5.8
1/2/14 | 18        | 2.3
1/2/14 | 23        | 1.3
1/3/14 | 11        | 15.9
1/3/14 | 17        | 20.1
```

There are some more columns but not necessary for this question. they are in 24 hour format, So 5 = 5AM, 17 = 5PM.
So I want to convert that a column which shows all hours used or unused. So it should be something like

```
Date    Hour ending   Amount(ltrs) 
1/2/14 | 1         | 0
1/2/14 | 2         | 0
1/2/14 | 3         | 0
1/2/14 | 4         | 0
1/2/14 | 5         | 0.5
1/2/14 | 6         | 0
1/2/14 | 7         | 0
...
..
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In your date you have values for 11 and 17 hours repeated twice. Does this mean you have to sum up amounts for those hours (10.5+15.9, 5.8+20.1)?

Comment: sorry that is for the next day I just changed it

Answer (score 0):

Make another table like your but with all hours specified in order, like in your second example. Say, your upper table is on `Sheet1` and the desired result is in `Sheet2`.

So in the cell `C2` in `Sheet2` you should have a formula like this:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,$B2)
```

Fill it down and here you are.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a column (say B) in your first sheet (say Sheet1) with B2:

```
=ROUND(A2+C2/24,14)
```

copied down to suit. In a second sheet insert `01/02/2014` in A1 and in A2:

```
=IF(B2=0,INT(A1)+1,INT(A1))+ROUND(B2/24,14)
```

in B2:

```
=MOD(ROW(),24)
```

in C2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROUND(A2,14),Sheet1!B:D,3,0),"")
```

and copy all three formulae down to suit. (A chart might be more useful.)